# How to show given function is $C_0^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I was reading theorem 8.15 in Gilberg Trudinger.

Theorem :

Let the operator L satisfy following conditions
$ a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\geq \lambda |\xi|^2,\qquad \forall x\in \Omega,\xi\in \mathbb R^n.
    $

$\sum|a^{ij}(x)|^2\leq \Lambda^2,\qquad \lambda^{-2}\sum (|b^i(x)|^2+|c^i(x)|^2)+\lambda^{-1}|d(x)|\leq \nu^2.$
$f^i\in L^q(\Omega),i=1,...,n$
$g\in L^{q/2}(\Omega) $ for some $q>n$.
If $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ sub(super) solution of equation $ Lu=g+D_if^i $ satisfying $u\le 0(\ge 0)$ on $\partial \Omega$

Then
\begin{equation}
\sup_{\Omega} u(-u)\le C(||u^+(u^-)||_2+k)
\end{equation}
Where $k=\lambda^{-1}(||f||_q+||g||_{q/2})$ and $C=C(n,\nu,q,|\Omega|)$

Proof:

We assume that $u $ is solution of $ Lu=g+D_if^i $. For $\beta\ge 1$ and $N>k$, let us define a function $H\in C^1[k,\infty)$ by setting $H(z)=z^{\beta}-k^{\beta}$ for $z\in [k,N]$ and taking H to be linear for $z\ge N $ . Let us next set $w=\overline{u}^+=u^++k$
and take
\begin{equation}\label{eq:835}
v=G(w)=\int_k^w|H'(s)|^2ds
\end{equation}
in the integral inequality
\begin{equation}\label{eq:830}
 \int_{\Omega}\left(D_ivA^i-vB\right)dx=(\le,\ge)0
 \end{equation}
By chain rule $v$ is test function .

Doubt:
To be a legitimate test function $v\in C_0^1$ but as $w\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ How $v$ to show $C_0^1(\Omega)$?

Any Help hint will be appreciated.